# How to maintain the icons size in different screen resolution in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to maintain the icons size according to different resolution on Xamarin forms?
I am using HeightRequest and WidthRequest for resize the icons but mu icons now showing responsive with different platforms.Is scale property works well for different resolution?
So how to maintain the icons size?